# Windows XP does not recognize setup.exe digital signature

Tags: c#, wpf, certificate, windows-xp, clickonce

Some time ago, I have published a WPF application using ClickOnce technology. The manifests are signed properly and when a customer downloads the setup.exe file the editor can be successfully verified:

[image]

However I noticed when the same setup.exe is downloaded from Windows XP operating system (still a requirements for the business) it seems the publisher cannot be verified.

[image]

How can I fix that? I supposed my certification would cover all Windows OSs, right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you see that message in Windows XP simply because that OS does not have any info about your Publisher in its secure publisher storage.
If the publisher was added to this storage not a long ago, Windows XP won't get the update that includes your Publisher's certificate info, so the OS is unable to check the validity of your application's digital signature.

Comment: Sounds reasonable @kralfy. I understand there is also a period of time so a "reputation" can be created. I confirm I had to wait some days, since my code signing is not "EV". I was monitoring that on Windows 10. Do you think this "reputation" is per OS version basis?

Comment: My previous comment question is because I recently downgrade my app to support WPF 4 and have the app running on Windows XP.

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas, I don't know for sure, so all I can do is to speculate, but anyway. As far as I know, Windows XP is not supported any more, that means that the OS won't receive any updates, including ones for Trusted Publishers Certificates storage. If this is so, you won't ever see your app successfully verified in Windows XP.

Comment: Although Windows XP displays this warning, if the user opens setup.exe file, then the Application Install with the publisher information is properly shown. I am wondering if this is because I signed the manifests only and not the assembly. Maybe if I sign assembly this could work, right?